# To add subcontext to parent list based upon number of suborders

Tags: python

ordernum,orderinfo,ordertxt has same length of lists.
ordernum list will have different numbers for 10 templates and need to automate it.

I want to generate a list automatically instead of a manual like below.

```
ordernum=[1,2,2.1,2.2,2.3,3,3.1,3.2,4,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,5,6]
orderinfo=['abc','defg','ghih','fghty','rtyui','rtyugh','dferty','sdftgy',
           'qwertf','zxcdf','vgtyu','iophjyu','wertyfg','qwsghjui','pouytfgh']

ordertxt=['dertfgt','dertyg234','htyrdf3456','cdserwe','','zsder453cv','','utryfgtygh',
          'jzsdf/nv3m','','rtyuio456','ghjktyrdfg','yufgr34fgty','hjkgh34ghty','ygfdswer']

orderdata=[]
orderdata.append({"orderid":ordernum[0],"orderdesc":orderinfo[0],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[0]}]})
orderdata.append({"orderid":ordernum[1],"orderdesc":orderinfo[1],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[1]}],"suborder":[{"orderid":ordernum[2],"orderdesc":orderinfo[2],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[2]}]},{"orderid":ordernum[3],"orderdesc":orderinfo[3],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[3]}]},{"orderid":ordernum[4],"orderdesc":orderinfo[4],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[4]}]}]})
orderdata.append({"orderid":ordernum[5],"orderdesc":orderinfo[5],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[5]}],"suborder":[{"orderid":ordernum[6],"orderdesc":orderinfo[6],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[6]}]},{"orderid":ordernum[7],"orderdesc":orderinfo[7],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[7]}]}]})
orderdata.append({"orderid":ordernum[8],"orderdesc":orderinfo[8],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[8]}],"suborder":[{"orderid":ordernum[9],"orderdesc":orderinfo[9],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[9]}]},{"orderid":ordernum[10],"orderdesc":orderinfo[10],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[10]}]},{"orderid":ordernum[11],"orderdesc":orderinfo[11],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[11]}]},{"orderid":ordernum[12],"orderdesc":orderinfo[12],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[12]}]}]})
orderdata.append({"orderid":ordernum[13],"orderdesc":orderinfo[13],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[13]}]})
orderdata.append({"orderid":ordernum[14],"orderdesc":orderinfo[14],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[14]}]})
```

The "suborder" needs to add based upon a number of times suborder numbers are there.
For example: For Order 2, 3 times need to add because 2.1,2.2,2.3 exists in "ordernum" list.
For Order 4, 4 times need to add because 4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4 exists in "ordernum" list.

Please help me to generate list automatically:

```
  def orderfunc1():
    orderdata=[]
    for i in range(len(ordernum)):
        if(ordernum[i]==int(ordernum[i])):
            print(ordernum[i])
            *<Need to add logic here>*
        else:
            print(ordernum[i])
            orderdata.append({"orderid":ordernum[i],"orderdesc":orderinfo[i],"text":[{"ordersent":ordertxt[i]}]})
        i-i+1
    return orderdata
```

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Naikum

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the task correctly, then something like this may help you:

```
def create_new_elem(i):
    elem = {
        "orderid": ordernum[i],
        "orderdesc": orderinfo[i],
        "text": [
            {"ordersent": ordertxt[i]}
        ],
    }
    return elem


def get_orderdata():
    orderdata = []
    current_elem = None
    for i, item in enumerate(ordernum):            
        if item == int(item):
            current_elem = create_new_elem(i)
            orderdata.append(current_elem)
        else:
            sub_elem = create_new_elem(i)
            current_elem.setdefault("suborder", []).append(sub_elem)

    return orderdata
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working fine. Simply superb solution. Thanks.